# What's the meaning of "it gets down to the midfifties"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, american-english

Can anyone help me understand what "the midfifties" means in this sentence? I found it in this [american novel](https://www.google.it/books/edition/A_Gracious_Neighbor/8SezzgEACAAJ?hl=it). To me, it could that the temperature goes down to about 55°F at night, because the main characters live in Houston and are accustomed to a warm climate, and here they're talking about the Napa Valley in California. But maybe I am misinterpreting?

> “Okay, well, it’s not only about wine. They have all these fabulous resorts and restaurants, too. We could go next weekend. Or this one, even! Heck, we could go tomorrow! As long as we’re back in time to pick Harry up on the fifteenth, we can be totally spontaneous. We could lounge by a hotel pool, or even go for a hot-air balloon ride if we wanted. I’ve always wanted to do that. Oh, and June’s off-season, so it’ll be cheap. Well, cheaper. And **it gets down to the midfifties at night**. Can you imagine?” Her eyes shone with excitement.

Comment: That is exactly what it means. You can guess what the 'mid fifties' are, maybe 54, 55, or 56.  Note that for me in the UK, a temperature in the 'mid fifties' would either kill me or send me to hospital with heat stroke.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - Or, for those of us who still think in Fahrenheit, it would be nothing to get excited about!